# Erro NoClassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document após atualizar o SDK

Tags: android, itext, android-sdk

Tenho um banco de dados em `sqlite` no Android, e exporto relatório para `pdf` usando a biblioteca `itextpdf`.

Mas recentemente após atualizar o SDK do Android, começou da erro na linha abaixo:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

O erro que ocorre:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document

Não modifiquei a classe, apenas atualizei a versão do SDK 22 para o SDK 23.

Estou com este problema em dispositivos anterior a Android 5.0. Da versão 5 em diante funciona normalmente.

**Antes:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

**Agora:**

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Alguem tem alguma sugestão do que pode ser?

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Sua pergunta está meio incompreensivel, um monte de código misturado com textos soltos, fica dificil entender. Primeiro explique o que está fazendo, depois o problema que está encontrando, somente ai adicione seu código e a mensagem de erro, assim ficará mais claro seu problema e a pergunta ficara de acordo com os padroes do site.

Comment: Este problema começou a aparecer depois que atualizei o sdk para o 23, uso o asynctask para chamar em background, mas dá erro. O estranho que é apenas em alguns dispositivos. O mesmo código funcionava bem antes, fiz o teste com os apk de debug e o único que funcionou em todos foi o que usava o sdk 22

Comment: Tenho dois dispositivo para testes, um com versão 5.1 que funciona normalmente é um com versão 4.3 que parou de gerar o pdf. Ainda não testei no emulador pois se funcionava antes, pode ser algo com a sdk não sei, sou iniciante na programação em Java. E não faço idéia por onde começar.

Comment: Dei uma melhorada na pergunta pra ficar mais fácil do pessoal entender, qualquer informação adicional que achar necessário, basta editar a pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado Diego, é a primeira vez que posto algo, pois não consegui encontrar uma solução.

Answer (score 2):

Problema resolvido.

No logcat aparecia a seguinte mensagem, antes do erro.

> Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.text.Document',

E pesquisando na internet, encontrei que poderia ser algo relacionado ao `multiDexEnabled` que não é necessário em versões anteriores, e também pelo fato de chamar todas as dependências do google `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`, que nesse caso removi que coloquei apenas o que precisava. foi ai que funcionou.

Na verdade não sei bem a solução porém alguma dependência do Google estava em conflito.

Mas serve de aviso para usar apenas o necessário e sempre verificar o logcat, que informava a falta da classe mesmo antes do erro.